# Retrieve File data without uploading (Express, Multer)

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, express, upload

I want to drag and drop to upload files from a Browser to an Express server that will hit the actual API to do the file upload. Therefore, the file does not need to be uploaded and saved anywhere on the Express server, it just needs to pass the data temporarily to the API call.

So from the browser, I upload to Express:

```js
onDrop = async newFiles => {
  let formData = new FormData()

  for (let i = 0; i < newFiles.length; i++) {
    let file = newFiles[i]

    formData.append('files', file)
  }

  try {
    const response = await axios.post('/upload', formData)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
```

And from Express I use Multer to retrieve the formData.

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const multer = require('multer')
const path = require('path')

const upload = multer({
  dest: 'path/to/uploads',
}).array('files')

router.post('/upload', preAuth, upload, async (request, response) => {
  const { files } = request
  // API call
})
```

But I just want to retrieve actual File temporarily without uploading it anywhere, and send it to the endpoint. I can't figure out any way to do this, or if it's even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `express-fileupload` to and `form-data` to accomplish my task of sending a multipart/formdata upload from the Browser to Express to another endpoint.

#### React Dropzone front end

```js
onDrop = async newFiles => {
  let formData = new FormData()

  for (let i = 0; i < newFiles.length; i++) {
    let file = newFiles[i]

    formData.append('files', file)
  }

  try {
    const response = await axios.post('/upload', formData)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

#### Express back end

```js
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')
app.use(fileUpload())
```

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const FormData = require('form-data')
const axios = require('axios')

router.post('/upload', preAuth, async (request, response) => {
  const { files } = request

  const formData = new FormData()

  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    let file = files[i]

    formData.append('files', file)
  }

  const formHeaders = formData.getHeaders()

  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post(
      `path/to/endpoint',
      formData,
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': formHeaders['content-type'],
          ...formHeaders,
        },
      }
    )
    response.status(200).send(data)
  } catch (error) {
    response.status(400).send({ message: 'Error'})
  }
})
```

Comment: Ultimately, this doesn't work. People of the future, just upload it somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

Basically the files are on request, that is in req.file, use this to pass it to the next middleware with next("file"). Maybe yo don't need Multer, use Cloudinary server and his API

Comment: I am aware of how to retrieve the files after uploading, I'm trying to see if I can retrieve them from the request without middleware to upload the files.